# How to set my custom Facebook page tab available for all people?

Tags: facebook, tabs

Following some Facebook instructions I have created a custom Facebook page tab with some content. Somehow the tab is only available for the account of the creator. When I login on Facebook with another account and view that page, the customer Facebook tab is not available.

What should I configure and how can I set that custom Facebook page tab available to everyone?

Answer (score 1):

Go to this page and select your app.
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

On the left side menu, select "Status and Review"
Make sure the toggle button for making it available to the general public.